# Weird permissions

Tags: macos, permission, acl

I moved to a new machine, and Migration Assistant failed miserably. I had to move files by hand, and in doing so some mighty strange things started happening.

I have finally tracked these down. Many of the files on both of the drives on this machine have a "Everyone: Custom" setting as the first permission. In this Custom setting, I don't have read/write, only read, and that means I can't (for instance) write to my own ~/Library

Disk Util was run, and resetpassword, and these each fixed some of the problems. I can edit most files, build in Xcode, etc.

But this did NOT fix my Library, so I can't (for instance) write to my keychain.

So... any suggestions on how to fix this? I know I want to remove all these Custom's, but perhaps there's some files in there that need them? Or should I simply chown everything in there and change the permissions to me read/write?

Comment: Do you have the migration log? If you can pinpoint what failed, fixing that might be easier than hand fixing your copy. Also, why not backup what you have and then re-run migration from that. The script ensures proper permissions as they are not all uniform on OSX

Comment: The problem is that MA can't figure out what to do when your user drive is not on your boot drive. And that's how I was set up.